# Big Cartel, Neat theme, how to remove the blur on featured products images once the site opens

Tags: html, blurry, bigcartel

I use Big cartel, Neat theme, for my website.

Whenever you open the home page, all the Featured products images blurs for sometimes 4 seconds or maight be more if you are not using chrome browser...

How can i remove this blur please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Bigcartel Neat theme

There is a `blur-up` class in product images at feature section.

```
<img alt="" class="blur-up product-list-image grid-default lazyautosizes lazyloaded" src="https://assets.bigcartel.com/product_images/152963788/2.jpg?auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;w=20">
```

Just remove the `blur-up` class to get remove initial loading blurry images.